# Set Background color in only (1/4)th portion of a View (Android)

Tags: android, textview, android-view

Is it possible to set background color for only (1/4)th portion of a View in Android? I have a use case where I need to select a view and color it after dividing it in portions, Ive looked at developer docs but I am unable to find a way to do the same.

Edit: I need to make it banded something like "| | | |" and I need to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is useful for you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"  >   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can I do this programatically, because I have to set color dynamically.

Comment: textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    //textview must be defined in your class

Comment: I want to set background color of 1/4th portion of textview not text color.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
 android:drawableTop="@drawable/....."
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">
  <TextView
      android:text="red"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aa0000"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:text="green"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#00aa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:text="blue"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#0000aa"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:text="yellow"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aaaa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```